# How to modify the content at the csv magento system to rtl

Tags: magento, csv, right-to-left

Recently i downloaded a template that support right-to-left because i need rtl theme.
I'm trying to change the csv files from english to hebrew-rtl language.
How can i do that? 
How can i set the new language in the admin panel?
I would glad to recieve some help.

Thanks and have a nice day.